# Load external pages using jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to load external pages into the current page without the user seeing the page load.

When I call the page 'info.php' it is loaded into the `#content` div. That's what the script is supposed to do.  The problem is that in the main page, which contains the script and the `#content` div, I already have some code that I want it to be executed when someone visits the page and not to be called from any external page. This is working but when I click on one of the links in the menu, I can't go back to the initial content.

Here is an except of my code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#nav a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page + '.php');
    return false;
    });
});
</script>

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="info">Info</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
Here I have some code that I wanted to be attributed to the "Page1"
</div>
```

Comment: You cant go back because you overwrite it without storing a copy of it. Store the contents in a variable, if someone clicks the Page1 link set the contents of the div to the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with load(), but in this case, I think you should be using ajax to load the page without refresh.

```
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
  url: page + '.php',
  success: function(data)
  {
     $('#content').html(data);
  }
})
```

EDIT: with you said "when I click on one of the links in the menu, I can't go back to the initial content", did you mean you have some code within the div #content and onclick you've overwritten its contents?

Comment: Exactly, When I visit the page, everything within the div #content is viewed, when I click on any tab of the menu, It's overwritten and I can't view it again

Comment: Okay, so you just create another div. That way you got 2 div tags and you just toggle them to hide and/or show. OR put that part you wanted to show onload of page, on another page and set it to show first, just like what you did for page+'.php'.

Comment: He trying to create something like jquery ui tabs with ajax loading. Example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html

Comment: @webdeveloper is right that's the case http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html except that the "preloaded" tab will be code that is written in the #content div and all the other tabs will be external pages

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
$(function()
{
   var content = $('#content');

   $('#nav a').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var page = $(this).attr('href');

       content.children().hide();
       var pageContent = content.find("#" + page);
       if(pageContent.length > 0)
       {
           pageContent.show();
       }
       else // put ajax here
       {
           content.append($('<div>').attr('id', page).text('New page ' + page));
       }
   });
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/3jLjw/](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLjw/)

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for me, though it seems to work fine in the demo.

Comment: @esandrkwn in `else` block, just add your ajax logic.

Comment: sure that's what I did, basically the else block should call external pages, sho I've added there my code but it didn't work - It's resulting Error 404

Comment: @user1688011 check server code and your paths in browser console.